# Mikrotik Download Limited

Tags: mikrotik

I have a Mikrotik routerboard RB2011UiAS.

I have an issue that when downloading we only get between 10mbit (1000pps) - 13mbit(1200pps) when connecting directly into the ISP provide with the Mikrotik.

If I put a hp procurve switch between the Mikrotik and ISP provider we get the full 100mbit download, how ever without we only get 10mbit - 13mbit.

Are they any settings or issue with the Mikrotik connecting directly with the ISP?

Comment: pps is a very different beast than mbit, as packet size can vary significantly. That said, are you sure the mikrotik is connecting at full duplex when it's directly conencted?

Comment: The Mikrotik is connected full duplex 100Mbps.

Comment: The procurve is Gigabit, right?

Comment: Yes, they are gigabit ports. The ISP equipment is only 100mbit.

Comment: What protocol do you use to connect to the ISP, PPP of some sort?

Comment: No, I use static IPs.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a ROS bug (what version are you running).  Have you tried creating a supout file and involving 'tik support?

As NickW points out this seems like a port negotiation issue.
Putting the Procurve between them certainly goes a long way towards pointing that.

Also, RB2011 has 5 Gbit and 5 10/100 ports.  Any change in behavior if you move the WAN port to other ports either on the Gbit half (ie 2-5) or over to the 10/100 side (6-10)?